# Signing with encrypted RSA key fails using jsrsasign

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, digital-signature

When using the library javascript library, jsrsasign with angularjs, we are attempting to RSA sign a value using a private key using SHA256 algorithm

the private key looks like the following:(i.e. -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----....-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----)

snippet:

```
var sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withRSA", "prov":   "cryptojs/jsrsa"});
var key = KEYUTIL.getKey(privateKey, 'password');
sig.initSign(key);
sig.updateString(data);
var signature = sig.sign();
```

In using this process, We receive the following error message on line two:
"bi.intValue is not a function"

In debugging it it appears that the value that is used has an alpha character that fails a function for the BigInteger library.

My first thought was it was the private key file, However, we are able to do the signing process using NodeJS's Crypto library and it works as expected.

I have tried different versions of the above with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution to this problem is associated to the includes libraries. This is not clear on the jsrsasign website. Since the error is very ambigious, it was difficult to tell at first. In order to get this to work you have include the following libraries

```
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/x64-core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/pbkdf2.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/hmac.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/crypto-js/sha256.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/base64.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/jsbn.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/jsbn2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/rsa.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/ext/rsa2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/crypto-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/rsasign-1.2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/rsapem-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/asn1-1.0.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/asn1hex-1.1.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jsrsasign/keyutil-1.0.js"></script>
```

After adding the necessary libraries, this returns a result. However, it is not the result expected. This is a separate issue, and will close this out